# How to type apostrophes in an easier way?

Tags: punctuation

I find typing

> `a word'

and

> ``a word''

quite inconvenient, because I find it rather annoying to type

> `

and

> ``

all the time. Instead, I'd prefer typing 'a word' and "a word" (which I often do when I don't pay attention, causing wrong displays). I was hoping the `inputenc` package would make this possible, but apparently it doesn't.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: No; if you type `b` instead of `a`, TeX will print a “b”, won't it? If you often use quotes, have a look at the `csquotes` package.

Comment: Emacs does this in `latex-mode` (i.e., smartly uses ``ẁord'' when I write "word").

Comment: I make `‘`, `’` and their doubled equivalents into active characters using `csquotes` and then type those directly. (Actually I only ever use the single ones.) The annoying thing is that I can't easily type them so I end up pasting them. I wish that my editor allowed me to specify custom quotation marks so that I didn't have to do this. My editor would autoreplace ``...'' etc. though. Just that is less flexible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible as LaTeX needs to know where a quotation is starting and where it ends. Imagine, you are writing

> "Outer with "inner quote"".

No chance for LaTeX to know, what you want. The accent (apostrophe) is used for other stuff as you can see in this example:

> I can't use what I've written.

So there are the following possibilities.

- You may search for an editor which auto-replaces your "" by “” and your '' by ‘’ as you are used to from existing office tools. TeXnicCenter does that, but I turned it off, as it was doing it to often i.m.o. (@jon mentions Emacs in `latex-mode`. Don't know it, but you may give it a try)
- You may try to get your correct quotation signs somehow into your code. Let's say copy it from somewhere or do a shortcut. Than you can use `csquotes` and define `\MakeAutoQuote{“}{”} \MakeAutoQuote*{‘}{’}` in order to make these signs active.
- Or you use the cleanest way, which I am using and define some single sign to be your quotation sign. I don't know, if you run in to problems somewhere with the < or >, but I can't find any situation right now. This would look like this:

  ```
  % arara: pdflatex

  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage{csquotes}
  \MakeAutoQuote{<}{>}

  \begin{document}
  \noindent<A double quote containing <a single quote>>. And in order to use the \textless{}-sign or the \textgreater{}-sign in the text, you will have to write the full command \verb+\textless{}+ or resp.\ \verb+\textgreater{}+ for them.
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: nice answer!  (i hope you don't mind my edits.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. Of course not. Especially for such ridiculous grammatical errors...